# context sharing in FreeGLUT under Linux with xorg

Tags: linux, opengl, freeglut, xorg, openglcontext

I am trying to use OpenGL with shared context (because of sharing textures between windows) via FreeGLUT library... It work fine, I can share textures, but i failed on the end of program or during windows closing by mouse...

I have cerated the code which emulate the problem: (http://pastie.org/9437038)

```
// file: main.c
// compile: gcc -o test -lglut main.c
// compile: gcc -o test -lglut -DTIME_LIMIT main.c

#include "GL/freeglut.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int winA, winB, winC;
  int n;

  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE , GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);
  //glutSetOption(GLUT_RENDERING_CONTEXT, GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
  winA = glutCreateWindow("Test A");
  glutSetOption(GLUT_RENDERING_CONTEXT, GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT);
  winB = glutCreateWindow("Test B");
  winC = glutCreateWindow("Test C");

  printf("loop\n");
  #ifdef TIME_LIMIT
  for (n=0;n<50;n++)
  {
    glutMainLoopEvent();

    usleep(5000);
  }
  #else //TIMELIMIT
  glutMainLoop();
  #endif // TIME_LIMIT

  printf("Destroy winC\n");
  glutDestroyWindow(winC);
  printf("Destroy winB\n");
  glutDestroyWindow(winB);
  printf("Destroy winA\n");
  glutDestroyWindow(winA);

  printf("Normal end\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
loop
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 (X_GLXDestroyContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  113
  Current serial number in output stream:  114
Segmentation fault
```

output with TIME_LIMIT:

```
loop
Destroy winC
Destroy winB
Destroy winA
Segmentation fault
```

Without calling glutSetOption(GLUT_RENDERING_CONTEXT, GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT);, it works well.

Do anybody have idea what am I doing bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT` does *not* create *shared contexts*. It just means that the *same* GL context is used for all windows. You only have one GL conxtext, and destroy it when you first destroy a window which uses that, so the other destruction calls fail. None of the GLUT implementations I'm aware of actually supports GL context sharing.

`GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT` is more like a hack (and it is nor part of the GLUT specification anyway), and not really a well-implemented. It could use some reference counting to destroy the context not before the last window using it is destroyed, but that is simply not the case.

Comment: Thanks. It explains the problem.